# Select row at the nth percentile

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`. Let the two tables contain date, id and latency column.

I have a simple query that performs a join on the two tables and returns a set of rows:

```
Select table1.date,(table2.latency - table1.latency) as ans from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.id order by ans;
```

I need to find the nth percentile row from the returned set of rows, lets say I need to find 90%, 99% and 99.9% percentile row from the data.

I need to display the data in a form like this:

```
    date       |   percentile  | ans
    01-12-1995 |    90         | 0.001563
    02-12-1999 |    99         | 0.0015
    05-12-2000 |    99.9       | 0.012
```

This is my first encounter to PostgreSQL. I am confused as to how should I proceed.

I was having a look at `PERCENT_RANK()` function. Please guide me in the correct direction.

Comment: Please provide sample data and explain the order in which the percentile should be calculated.

Comment: tip use SQLfiddle to provide us with example data.. you should really elaborate your question more.. and it looks like you want to use date as an GROUP where columns `percentile` and `ans` (looks like an SUM) depends on

Comment: well i need the exact/closest row indicating that it is the 90 percentile value for the given set of data.so when i get the row, i want to display only that particular row.

Comment: You *need* to declare the version of Postgres you are working with. And, of course, an sqlfiddle or any kind of sample data would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the window function [**`ntile()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery (requires Postgres 8.4 or later).
Then select the segments you are interested in (corresponding to percentiles) and pick the row with the lowest value from it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (segment)
       the_date, to_char((segment - 1)/ 10.0, '99.9') AS percentile, ans
FROM  (
    SELECT t1.the_date 
          ,ntile(1000) OVER (ORDER BY (t2.latency - t1.latency)) AS segment
          ,(t2.latency - t1.latency) AS ans
    FROM   table1 t1
    JOIN   table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   ) sub
WHERE  segment IN (601, 901, 991, 1000)
ORDER  BY segment, ans;
```

The Postgres-specific `DISTINCT ON` comes in handy for the last step. Detailed explanation in this related answer on SO:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

To get the `90`, `99` and `99.9` percentile I picked the matching granularity with `ntile(1000)`. And added a `60` percentile as per comment.

This algorithm picks the row *at or above* the exact value. You can add a line to the subquery with `percent_rank()` to get the *exact relative rank* of the select row in addition:

```
 percent_rank() OVER (ORDER BY (t2.latency - t1.latency)) AS pct_rank
```

Aside: I replaced the column name `date` with `the_date` since I am in the habbit of avoiding [reserved SQL key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers, even if Postgres would permit them.

Comment: @D3XT3R: Actually my selection of segments was off. I fixed that and added the row above 60%.

Comment: so how do you base your selection of segments..i mean lets say.. i want to display percentile value of 100 percentile within the same algorith. as per your algorithm, i need to provide the segments of data i want to create, am i on the correct track?

Comment: Since I divided the rows into 1000 segments, the lowest value of the 601st (or the highest value of the 600th) would mark the 60% border ...

Comment: thanks erwin..how can i get the last row of the table i.e. the 100 percentile value? should i divide the rows into further more segments?

Comment: @D3XT3R: Use a descending order and add `LIMIT 1` to get the *last* row in a simple query.. `SELECT * FROM .. ORDER BY ans DESC LIMIT 1`. Or, in the above query, to pick the row with the highest value from the segment, add `DESC` at the very end. You would pick the segments `(600, 900, 990, 1000)` in this case and adapt the `to_char()` expression accordingly.